# NoMethodError in Usuario#new RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**controller:**

```
class UsuarioController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @usuarios = Usuario.order :nome
    end

    def new 
        @usuario = Usuario.new
    end

    def show
        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])
        @usuario.destroy

        redirect_to(action: "index")
    end

end
```

**View:**

## Novo Usuário

```
<%= form_for @usuario do |f| %>
  Nome: <%= f.text_field :nome %><br/>
<% end %>
```

**Error:**

```
  NoMethodError in Usuario#new
Showing /vagrant/crudexemplo/app/views/usuario/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `usuarios_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fce441b1e20>:0x007fce31f1e148>
```

Comment: Faz o seguinte verifica as rotas usando rake routes e depois cola aqui pra gente olhar. rake routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar a rota no config/routes.rb

```
Sample::Application.routes.draw do
  #outras rotas...

  resource :usuario #adicione essa linha
end
```

e o nome do controller sempre no plural ex.: UsuariosController

Comment: Cara eu já tenho adicionado :|

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :usuario
  root 'usuario#index'
  get '/login' => 'usuario#index'

Comment: está "usuario" e não "usuarios"

Comment: mas porque tem quer ser em plural ?

Comment: Não funcionou ..

Comment: resources para plural e resource pra singular

Ex.: **resources :usuarios ou resource :usuario**

o nome do controller está no singular então utilize resource* ao invés de resources*

Comment: normalmente se usa nome do controller no plural, você pode colocar ele no plural e fazer conforme eu tinha respndido antes, ou simplesmente usar a rota no singular mesmo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33058/discussion-between-user2842966-and-jose-vieira-neto).

Comment: Não tenho reputação para falar no chat..

Comment: Renomei o controller e funcionou .